# Need plots of two line graphs on same chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using R, I have two line graphs each in their own chart. I need them both on the same chart. I have looked at other stackoverflow inquiries but did not find one that matches my need.

In my two-line chart I need graphs for BA and careerBA on the vertical axis and the G field as the horizontal axis. Each G value (e.g., 1) has a matching BA and careerBA.

```
BA <- c(0.317, 0.298, 0.273, 0.280, 0.252, 0.204, 0.181, 0.241, 0.227, 0.233, 0.080, 0.285)

careerBA <- c(0.279, 0.280, 0.245, 0.253, 0.276, 0.247, 0.265, 0.243, 0.274, 0.255, 0.236, 0.287)

G <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)

df <- data.frame(BA, careerBA, G)
df

library(ggplot2)
p1 <- ggplot() + geom_line(aes(y = BA, x = G, color = "red"), data = df) + labs(title = "All Mets Age 37 Season", x = "Games", y = "Batting Average", caption = "Age 37 Mets") + scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,160,20))
p1


p2 <- ggplot() + geom_line(aes(y = BAcareer, x = G), data = age37mets, color = "blue") + labs(title = "All Mets Age 37 Career", x = "Games", y = "Career Batting Average", caption = "Age 37 Mets") + scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,160,20))
p2
```

Here is my dput:

```
structure(list(BA = c(0.317, 0.298, 0.273, 0.28, 0.252, 0.204, 
0.181, 0.241, 0.227, 0.233, 0.08, 0.285), careerBA = c(0.279, 
0.28, 0.245, 0.253, 0.276, 0.247, 0.265, 0.243, 0.274, 0.255, 
0.236, 0.287), G = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to reshape your data into a longer format (here I'm using `pivot_longer` function from `tidyr` package):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% pivot_longer(-G, names_to = "var",values_to = "val")

# A tibble: 24 x 3
       G var        val
   <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
 1     1 BA       0.317
 2     1 careerBA 0.279
 3     2 BA       0.298
 4     2 careerBA 0.28 
 5     3 BA       0.273
 6     3 careerBA 0.245
 7     4 BA       0.28 
 8     4 careerBA 0.253
 9     5 BA       0.252
10     5 careerBA 0.276
# … with 14 more rows
```

If you want to add the plotting part, you can wrote:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

df %>% pivot_longer(-G, names_to = "var",values_to = "val") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = G, y = val, color = var))+
  geom_line()+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x){format(x, nsmall = 3)})
```

[image]

Is it what you are looking for ?

Comment: dc37, that is almost exactly what I need. On the vertical axis, how can I get the decimals to appear as three digits after the decimal point, e.g., 0.300 instead of 0.30?

Comment: I edited my answer accordingly. You can have the use of `format` function from `scales` library. Does it answer your question ?

Comment: That looks great. Can you recommend a source that explains how to use both pivot_longer and the format function in the scales library?

Comment: Actually, the `format` function that I used is not from `scales` but from `base`. So, just doing `?format` should give you the explanation of this function. For `pivot_longer`, you can check this link: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html. Otherwise, you have plenty of ressources and questions/answers on SO about those